# Rails console - up arrow not working for last command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having small problem with the rails console in Rails 3.

I'm using a Mac and zsh in terminal.  When I run the rails console I'm prompted with this:

```
ruby-head :001 >
```

When I try to use the up arrow to repeat last command I get an error sound and the command is not shown.  Also to use tab as auto complete I have to press tab twice.

Another problem is that it takes about 10 seconds from I give the rails console command until the console is displayed.  Is that normal?

Regards,
Johann

Comment: Hello - I didn't know of this feature (took some time to figure out).  I have accepted the answers that have been resolved.  Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Does the up arrow work normally in your shell?

Comment: Tried switching to bash and that didn't fix anything for me. However strangely pushing the left or right arrow key just before I push the up arrow key allows me to start using the up arrow like normal. Is this the same for you?

Comment: Ok figured out my issue was "set editing-mode vi" in .inputrc

Comment: Did that solve your problem too?

Answer (score 8):

Check for a file in your home directory called **.inputrc** and see if it contains:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

For me that was the issue and removing that line sets things back to normal. Now I'm just wondering how on earth that file ended up getting created.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I thought I was going crazy when this was happening to me just now.  No clue how it got changed :-/

Comment: I have the same problem, but my .inputrc file does not contain that line :/